# web2py reference field unique=True attribute not working

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

I working with web2py and have the following table definition:

```
my_info = db.define_table('my_info',
    Field('my_info_id', 'reference other_info', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, other_info.id, ''), unique=True),
    Field('interface', 'string', length=32, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('size', 'integer', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]))
```

For some reason when I view the mysql create table syntax I do not see the UNIQUE_KEY field set. Here is the create table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `mgmt_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `my_info_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interface` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id__idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`my_info_id`) REFERENCES `other_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Hope someone can let me know why I am not able to set a foreign key to unique and why it does not work.

Thanks,
nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd, but odder is that in your unique field you did put the IS_IN_DB validator. I do not know what you wanted to do, but you should replace by IS_NOT_IN_DB validator. Therefore, it will assure to you that your field 'my_info_id' is unique in your database.

Comment: I was trying to make a foreign key unique which does not really make sense in hindsight. This is why unique did not work in web2py however it is not impossible to do in pure MySQL if one wanted to do that.